# Nodejs request issue with especific endpoint (Client network socket disconnected)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my entire code

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

(async () => {
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    Host: 'www.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
    Pragma: 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
  };

  const jar = rp.jar();

  try {
    const firstAccess = await rp.get('https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaSituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp', {
      headers,
      gzip: true,
      simple: false,
      strictSSL: false,
      jar,
    });
    console.log(firstAccess);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

When i run my code i receive this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Error: Client network
>   socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

The url works in the browser, but I can not access through nodeJS, apparently it's some problem with the https certificate

Is there any way to ignore the error and access it?

Comment: why do you want to use `request-promise` instead of `fetch()`?

Comment: Here is a discussion https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21088

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your call inside a try catch block to handle the promise rejection in case the call fails:

```
...
try {
  const firstAccess = await rp.get(...)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
...
```

Comment: message:
   'Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established',

Comment: The url works in the browser, but I can not access through nodeJS, apparently it's some problem with the https certificate

Is there any way to ignore the error and access it?

Comment: It may be caused by missing headers from your nodejs request. What are the headers in the browser request?

Comment: Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    Host: 'www.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
    Pragma: 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',

Comment: I`m using all of them

Comment: Baboo, Can you access the link in your browser and try to run the code?

Comment: is there any solution?? I have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was resolved after restarting/changing the network connection. The issue is with the network most of the time.

Comment: Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: reason for the same is proxy, if your network is behind proxy like fiddler etc. the TLS will not be authenticated, and the response will be sent ahead of the handshake.